# Django sites on different ports - showing up at serveraddress:8000 not serveraddress/app1

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a two Django instances with two separate virtualenvs that I am trying to have on two suburls: serveraddress/app1 and serveraddress/app2. I have my Apache virtual hosts setup as below and am using mod_wsgi.

The Django instance I am putting at port 8000 in the Apache settings shows up at this url:
`http://serveraddress:8000/app1` rather than `http://serveraddress/app1`. App2  on port 80 shows up at the right url - `http:/serveraddress/app2`.

How do I get `http:/serveraddress:8000/app1` to show up at `http://serveraddress/app1`?

```
<VirtualHost serveraddress:8000>
ServerName serveraddress
WSGIDaemonProcess app1 python-    path=/var/www/app1:/var/www/app1/files:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
WSGIProcessGroup app1
WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /var/www/app1/files/files/wsgi.py
AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /var/www/app1/files/app1/static/css/$1
Alias /media/  /var/www/app1/files/media/
Alias /static/ /var/www/app1/files/app1/static/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost serveraddress:80>
ServerName serveraddress
WSGIDaemonProcess app2 python-path=/var/www/app2-files:/var/www/app2-files/app2-    files:/var/www/app2-files/env2/lib/python2.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup app2
WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /var/www/app2-files/app2-files/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

And in my ports.conf I have:

```
NameVirtualHost serveraddress:80
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost serveraddress:8000
Listen 8000
```

Comment: But... you're serving it at port 8000. How else did you expect this to work? If you don't want it to appear at port 8000, don't serve it there, surely?

Comment: I had to serve it at 8000 because I could not get both at port 80. It would either serve one or the other. I'm now trying a reverse proxy to get the http:/serveraddress:8000/app1 to show at http://serveraddress/app1.